# 'Invalid SQL Statement' when creating PL/SQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In an Oracle DB I have the following two tables:

```
Task (TaskID, ..., AuthorID)
Author (AuthorID, level)
```

where `AuthorID` in `Task` represents the author that wrote the task. Now I wrote the following procedure, that is supposed to update `level`-Attribute based on the number of tasks the author has written.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE profil_level
IS
    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT AuthorID, COUNT(AuthorID) as Total FROM Task
       GROUP BY AuthorID;
    result c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
        LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO result;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

      IF(result.Total = 2 OR result.Total = 3) THEN
        UPDATE TABLE Author SET level = 'advanced' 
            WHERE AuthorID = result.AuthorID;
      END IF;

      IF(result.Total >= 4) THEN
        UPDATE TABLE Author SET level= 'proficient'
            WHERE AuthorID = result.AuthorID;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Trying to execute this statement, I get tons of errors like

> invalid SQL Statement

e.g. for the line `result c1%ROWTYPE` or `FETCH c1 into result`. Additionally, I get the error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of
>   the following: ...

for the line `BEGIN OPEN c1`. I cannot figure out, what the problem is with my code. I've read tutorials from Oracle and on other sites, but in every example I've seen so far, they have used the exact same syntax. Do I need to change the 'delimiter' (like e.g. in MySQL)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are using SQL*Plus, you need to terminate the `create table` with a `/` (on a single line)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have tried that already, but it made no difference (just checked again).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Did you really mean the `create table` statement or is it just a typo and you meant `create procedure`? edit: Yes, I am aware of that (but there are people who want me to specifically create a procedure ;-))

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant `create procedure`. See the link I posted and click on build schema.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Great link - thanks! I tried to build the schema with my entire code, but it did not work (check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/931a9)). There must be something wrong with my code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found the problem: the update statement within the if-clause was erroneous. It's supposed to be:

```
UPDATE Author SET level = 'advanced' 
            WHERE AuthorID = result.AuthorID;
```

instead of

```
UPDATE TABLE Author SET level = 'advanced' 
            WHERE AuthorID = result.AuthorID;
```

Comment: Good answer. :) I'm new about pl/sql, your question & answer really helpful to me.

Comment: @lv0gun9 this is not a good coding pattern to learn from. Explicit cursors are to be avoided when possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658505/pl-sql-executing-procedure-fails-and-unable-to-retrieve-compile-warnings

Answer (score 1):

Error #1: LEVEL is a reserved word in PL/SQL

I tried the rest of your code without the IFs and it looks good - so this
will compile (see below).  Yes, the IF's have UPDATE TABLE - the word TABLE
should not be there (Error #2)

** Just don't use LEVEL as a column name. **

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE profil_level
IS
    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT FIELD1, COUNT(FIELD1) AS TOTAL FROM T1
      GROUP BY FIELD1;
    result c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
        LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO result;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;


        END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Comment: I tried to compile the procedure without the IF's, too, but it failed anyway.