# PL/SQL executing procedure fails and unable to retrieve compile warnings

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In an earlier post, I had some problems with compiling the procedure below (which is supposed to update the attribute `profile` based on how many tasks an author has written) - now, it does compile (with warnings though) and when I try to execute it, it fails. I cannot figure out why. I'm using ExecuteQuery to connect to a remote Oracle database. The tables involved in the procedure are:

```
Task(TaskID, ..., AuthorID)
Author(AuthorID, profile, name, ...)
```

Here is the procedure (my specific questions follow below):

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='ENABLE:ALL';
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE profil_stufe
IS
    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT AuthorID, COUNT(AuthorID) as Total FROM Task
                 GROUP BY AuthorID;
    result INTEGER c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
        LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO result;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

      IF(result.Total = 2 OR result.Total = 3) THEN
        UPDATE Author SET profile = 'Advanced' WHERE AuthorID = result.AuthorID;
      END IF;

      IF(result.Total >= 4) THEN
        UPDATE Author SET profile = 'proficient' WHERE AuthorID = result.AuthorID;
         END IF;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
END;
```

My questions:

1. First of all, I am not able to retrieve the warnings produced when compiling the procedure. I tried queries like `select plsql_warnings from user_plsql_object_settings ps where ps.name = 'profil_stufe';` or `select * from user_errors ur where ur.name = 'profil_stufe';` but neither deliver any result, even though the procedure does compile with warnings.
2. When I perform `execute profil_stufe` I get an error

> ORA-06550: Row 1, Column 16: PLS-00905: object CS261_20.PROFIL_STUFE
>   is invalid ORA-06550: Row 1, Column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Can somebody help me out? I know, that I could avoid creating a procedure and implement the same functionality otherwise. But it seems like I am missing some basic concepts of PL/SQL and I would really like to get to understand them ... So, thanks for your help!

Comment: as its resolved, for future refrence, the objectname should be uppercase by default. ie `select * from user_errors ur where ur.name = 'PROFIL_STUFE';` (only use mixed/lower if you've created the object with double quotes eg `create procedure "profil_stufe"` (not recommended in oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you have the variable declaration as : `result INTEGER c1%ROWTYPE;`
It should be `result c1%ROWTYPE;`

Comment: Well, that is a very good question :) Thanks for that! Now, it did compile without warning and did not fail when executing! Do you happen to know as well, how I can check compile-warnings in the db?

Comment: you can use in sqlplus :: SHOW ERRORS...I use SQLDEVELOPER which give weird red underline for any issue such as above..Please don't forget to accept the answer..Happy coding!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the real problem here is that your coding practice has led you to an unnecessarily complex solution, in which you have introduced an error.

You should try to reduce your use of cursors, explicit ones in particular, and minimise the number of SQL statements executing particularly when you execute one DML statement for each row of a result set.

Here I've converted your logic to a MERGE statement and limited the number of rows being returned from he task query with a HAVING clause. It's a MERGE because Oracle's UPDATE syntax is not as flexible as that of other systems.

```
 create or replace procedure profil_stufe
 is
 begin
   merge into
     author tgt
   from (
     select   authorid,
              case when count(*) >= 4
                then 'proficient'
                else 'Advanced'
              end profile
     from     task
     group by authorid
     having   count(*) >= 2) src
   on (src.author_id = tgt.author_id)
   when matched then update
   set profile = src.profile
 end;
```

Syntax above not checked on a real system, but should be close.

Anyway, this method should be:

1. Faster, because it is a single query that will also process less data.
2. More robust because the code is simpler.
3. More easily testable because the MERGE statement's USING query can be easily tested in isolation and the entire MERGE statement can be run in SQL*Plus.